# Who is this pink-caped superheroine?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero

My daughter wears a shirt that she calls her Supergirl shirt. The character printed on it looks like no version of Supergirl I have seen. See image below.

Judging from the dashing cape and power pose, I assume she's meant to be a superhero. The shirt is secondhand, so if there was ever any copyright information, it's faded away. Web searches for things like `pink caped superhero` and `superhero star s` turn up nothing that resembles her.

Is she an actual superheroine with a backstory, comic, and special powers, or just a generic character created for kids' clothing?

[image: pink superhero character]

Edit: This is the only labeling I can find. The shirt is a long-sleeve.

[image: shirt label]

Comment: Generic Superhero Girl to the rescue!

Comment: I have never seen any superheroine remotely looking like this. My guess is generic, to avoid paying license.

Comment: Agreed - Generic! If you search free supergirl clipart, you get a lot of results that look very similar to this. Couldn't find an exact match but most give off the same vibe.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to identify the individual through facial features, because of the mask.

Comment: Can you post the label? Even if it's faded, it might offer some useful info.

Comment: @Valorum I edited an image of the label into the question.

Comment: Might be useful to clarify whether this was a long-sleeved or short-sleeved shirt.

Comment: @pmcoltrane - Cheers. The label has allowed me to answer the question. Sadly, it's a piece of generic artwork.

Comment: Not [Kekko Kamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kekko_Kamen) (NSFW)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of the [PEKKLE range of children's clothing](https://poshmark.com/brand/Pekkle), produced by a company called Group Lemur, Inc. and typically (but not exclusively) sold in Costco.

[image]

This brand uses [generic artwork of their own design](https://east.cocowest1.ca/uploads/2018/10/20181001_155148.jpg). It's unlikely that this particular superhero has any backstory, other than offering super low prices.